# C# How do I combine values in a list of name value pairs that have the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concatenation

I have a list that contains name/value pairs

Class looks like this:

```
string Name { get; set; }
string Value { get; set; }
```

What I need to do is concatenate all of the values that have the same name into a new list where the class looks like this:

```
string Name { get; set; }
list<string> Values { get; set; }
```

Comment: Think you might want to look at this: [ToLookup()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: `var combined = nvpList.GroupBy(nvp => nvp.Name).Select(group => new NameValueClass {Name = group.Key, Values = group.SelectMany(nvp => nvp.Values).Distinct().ToList()});`

Comment: Rufus you saved the day.  This is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ `GroupBy` method:

```
var result = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.Name, x => x.Value, 
    (k, g) => new YouSecondClass { Name = key, Values = g.ToList() });
```